# Dealing with OS Error Python: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Volumes/ARLO/ADNI/.DS_Store'

Tags: python, operating-system

I am trying to write a piece of code that will recursively iterate through the subdirectories of a specific directory and stop only when reaching files with a '.nii' extension, appending these files to a list called images - a form of a breadth first search. Whenever I run this code, however, I keep receiving [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/Volumes/ARLO/ADNI/.DS_Store'

*/Volumes/ARLO/ADNI is the folder I wish to traverse through

*I am doing this in Mac using the Spyder IDE from Anaconda because it is the only way I can use the numpy and nibabel libraries, which will become important later

*I have already checked that this folder directly contains only other folders and not files

```
#preprocessing all the MCIc files
import os
#import nibabel as nib
#import numpy as np

def pwd():
    cmd = 'pwd'
    os.system(cmd)
    print(os.getcwd())

#Part 1
os.chdir('/Volumes/ARLO')
images = [] #creating an empty list to store MRI images
os.chdir('/Volumes/ARLO/ADNI')
list_sample = [] #just an empty list for an earlier version of 
#the program

#Part 2
#function to recursively iterate through folder of raw MRI 
#images and extract them into a list
#breadth first search
def extract(dir):
    #dir = dir.replace('.DS_Store', '')
    lyst = os.listdir(dir) #DS issue
    for item in lyst:
        if 'nii' not in item: #if item is not a .nii file, if 
#item is another folder
            newpath = dir + '/' + item
            #os.chdir(newpath) #DS issue
            extract(newpath)
        else: #if item is the desired file type, append it to 
#the list images
            images.append(item)

#Part 3           
adni = os.getcwd() #big folder I want to traverse
#print(adni) #adni is a string containing the path to the ADNI 
#folder w/ all the images
#print(os.listdir(adni)) this also works, prints the actual list
"""adni = adni + '/' + '005_S_0222' 
os.chdir(adni)
print(os.listdir(adni))""" #one iteration of the recursion, 
#works
extract(adni)
print(images)
```

With every iteration, I wish to traverse further into the nested folders by appending the folder name to the growing path, and part 3 of the code works, i.e. I know that a single iteration works. Why does `os` keep adding the '.DS_Store' part to my directories in the `extract()` function? How can I correct my code so that the breadth first traversal can work? This folder contains hundreds of MRI images, I cannot do it without automation.

Thank you.

Comment: "I have already checked that this folder directly contains only other folders and not files." How did you check? Files starting with a `.`, like `.DS_Store`, are not shown by `ls` unless you pass the `-a` flag, and are not shown in Finder unless you enable hidden files. Also, the `os` module doesn't create these files, Finder does (or sometimes Spotlight, I think).

Comment: Also, why are you trying to build the equivalent of `os.walk` yourself (but more complicated, and handling fewer edge cases) instead of just using `os.walk`?

Comment: @abarnert I was in fact using Finder to see these files. Thank you for letting me know about hidden files. Additionally, I only just familiarized myself with the basics of the `os` module and did not know about `os.walk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.DS_Store`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) files are not being created by the `os` module, but by the Finder (or, I think, sometimes Spotlight). They're where macOS stores things like the view options and icon layout for each directory on your system.

And they've probably always been there. The reason you didn't see them when you looked is that files that start with a `.` are "hidden by convention" on Unix, including macOS. Finder won't show them unless you ask it to show hidden files; `ls` won't show them unless you pass the `-a` flag; etc.

So, that's your core problem:

> I have already checked that this folder directly contains only other folders and not files

… is wrong. The folder *does* contain at least one regular file; `.DS_Store`.

So, what can you do about that?

You could add special handling for `.DS_Store`.

But a better solution is probably to just check each file to see if it's a file or directory, by calling [`os.path.isdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) on it.

Or, even better, use [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) instead of `listdir`, which gives you entries with more information than just the name, so you don't need to make extra calls like `isdir`.

Or, best of all, just throw out this code and use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to recursively visit every file in every directory underneath your top-level directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for identifying the problem for me. I did try `os.walk` but that only returns the isolated filenames, and if I need to extract the MRI images, I need the entire file paths of all these images. Do you have any tips as to how I can get these?

Comment: @arnavlohe15 The short version is: `pathname = os.path.join(root, filename)`, but just look at the docs for `os.walk`; all of the examples show how to do it.